# How to enable Scroll in dexexpress gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I googled a lot for enabling the scroll in dex express gridview.but no result.

I have a gridview as you can see :

[image]

As you can see the gridview doesn't have scroll .I want to change it like this :

[image]

I set autocolumn property to false but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the Auto Column Width to false:

```
gridView.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = false;
```

You can do that through the designer following the same hierarchy (`GridView Designer =>  OptionsView => ColumnAutoWidth`)

You can AutoFit All Columns afterwards to make it look better:

```
gridView.BestFitColumns();
```

Comment: How can i set autofit colums ?

Comment: @user6538993 that can be done at run-time using code. Check the edit. You can't do it at design-time because it is a method and not a property. And it is based on the data in each column, so it doesn't make any sense to be at design-time.